# Bootstrap Popover/Tooltip for mapped areas on an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to combine the Bootstrap pack from Twitter and an image that I have mapped out so that portions will--when rolled over--produce a popover/tooltip next to the mapped area. Here's what I've done so far:

1. I mapped using CSS instead of the old Image Map way. The code is below.
2. The image and the areas on it are visible and highlight when rolled over.

Now I've been able to make the popover appear but it is always fixated on the upper left of the image (even when the original image is repositioned).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Image Map</title>

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style_common.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style5.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <a href="#" id="jon" rel="popover" data-original-title="Milage Rate"
                data-content="Content..."><div id="milagerate"></div></a> <a
                href="#"><div id="fairmarketvalue"></div></a> <a href="#"><div
                    id="netassessment"></div></a> <a href="#"><div id="adjustedfmv"></div></a>
            <a href="#"><div id="exemptions"></div></a> <a href="#"><div
                    id="taxablevalue"></div></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#jon').popover({
                placement : 'bottom'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

a {
    color:white;
}

#wrapper{
    background:white url(PB.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:0;
    width:530px;
    height:570px;
}

#milagerate {
    position:absolute;
    width:27px;
    height:17px;
    top:346px;
    left:347px;
}

#fairmarketvalue {
    position:absolute;
    width:56px;
    height:15px;
    top:319px;
    left:177px;
}

#netassessment {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:17px;
    top:346px;
    left:194;
}

#adjustedfmv {
    position:absolute;
    width:51px;
    height:17px;
    top:346px;
    left:141px;
}

#exemptions {
    position:absolute;
    width:51px;
    height:17px;
    top:346px;
    left:245px;
}

#taxablevalue {
    position:absolute;
    width:51px;
    height:17px;
    top:346px;
    left:295px;
}

#milagerate:hover, #fairmarketvalue:hover, #netassessment:hover, #adjustedfmv:hover, #exemptions:hover, #taxablevalue:hover {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

How do I force the popover to appear next to the mapped areas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I got some help and I've fixed the problems I was initially having. My problem was that the popover code was associated with my anchor (the picture) instead of the contents. That being said, I had to use the individual IDs for each piece of the contents:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#jon').popover({
            placement : 'right'
        });

        $('#jon2').popover({
            placement : 'right'
        });

        $('#jon3').popover({
            placement : 'right'
        });

        $('#jon4').popover({
            placement : 'right'
        });

        $('#jon5').popover({
            placement : 'right'
        });

        $('#jon6').popover({
            placement : 'right'
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in the CSS, I followed this pattern:

```
...
#thing1, #jon3 {
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:17px;
    top:346px;
    left:194px;
}

#thing2, #jon4 {
    position:absolute;
    width:51px;
    height:17px;
    top:346px;
    left:141px;
}
...
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to approach this problem, but for the moment this code works perfectly for me.

Comment: That makes sense. Odd that you would have to use the individual IDs though. Would it not work to simply add a class (say "jons") to each of the anchors and then use $(".jons").popover({ placement: 'right' });

Answer (score 1):

Use the "placement" attribute

See the documentation for the tootip here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: I'm using it already in the code above. It's changing the direction the arrow of the popover is facing, but the popover never moves to sit beside the area I have it associated with.

Comment: Interesting, it's hard to really know what's going on without seeing it and being able to play with it. Unfortunately, bootstrap is a customized download. Do you know what settings you used so that I can try to duplicate the issue?

Comment: I just downloaded the normal package, then just found the individual portions of bootstrap that I needed (bootstrap-tooltip.js and bootstrap-popover.js). Here's a jsFiddle for ya http://jsfiddle.net/5L4Kv/5/

Comment: That's weird, I thought I pasted it correctly. Here it is again: http://jsfiddle.net/5L4Kv/6/ If you're wondering what to hover over it's the "Milage Rate" on the pic (I know it's hard to read on small screens).

Comment: nope, sorry - one of the reason's why bootstrap is so difficult to debug is that it does not work very well in fiddle and the code is only customizable when you configure the download package